# Program stuck at scanf

Tags: c

so basically I'm trying to write a program as an exercise from my textbook where the user inputs a 12 digits number, and after a series of operations, a "check digits" gets printed out. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0, seven = 0,
      eight = 0, nine = 0, ten = 0, eleven = 0, twelve = 0;
  int check_digit;

  printf("Enter the first 12 digits of an EAN: ");
  scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, 
                                    &eight, &nine, &ten, &eleven, &twelve);

  check_digit = 9 - (((two + four + six + eight + ten + twelve)*3 +
            (one + three + five + seven + nine + eleven))-1)%10;

  printf("Check digit: %d\n\n", check_digit);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the program outputs absolutely nothing and it never seems to go past the scanf as I'm always able to add more digits even after inputting the 12 initial ones and hitting enter. I don't even get any warnings or errors whatsoever.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `%1d` or just read the input as a string with `"%s"`. The code you have will only work if you put spaces between the digits.

Comment: ohh yes works with %1d... I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: OT:  the `scanf()` family of functions returns a value.  that value indicates how many of the input format specifiers where successfully input.  The code should always check that value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Note: `check_digit = 9 - (((two + four + six + eight + ten + twelve)*3 +
            (one + three + five + seven + nine + eleven))-1)%10;` has a corner problem when input is `"000000000000"`, `check_digit` will take on a value of 10.  To handle that and not mess up other `% 10` calculation, simply replace `- 1` with `+ 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your scanf is using `%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d`. It is expecting 12 numbers. So if you typed in `123456789012`, the program scan in just 1 number. It reads `123456789012` not how you want it where `one = 1`, then `two = 2` etc.

You can solve this by changing your scanf to:

`scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five, &six, &seven, &eight, &nine, &ten, &eleven, &twelve);`

%1d will read a single digit. So now it will do what you want it to, where `one = 1`, then `two = 2` etc.

Another way to solve this would be reading the number as a string. The convert the string into an int array. I've provided the code for how to do that below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE        12

// Function prototypes
void str_arr_to_int_arr(char str[], int num[], int len);
int check_digit(int EAN[], int len);

int main(void) {

    char EAN_str[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    int EAN_int[MAX_SIZE + 1];

    printf("Enter the first 12 digits of an EAN: ");
    scanf("%12s", EAN_str);

    str_arr_to_int_arr(EAN_str, EAN_int, MAX_SIZE);

    int answer = check_digit(EAN_int, MAX_SIZE);

    printf("Check digit: %d\n", answer);

    return 0;
}

// This function will convert a char array into an int array
void str_arr_to_int_arr(char str[], int num[], int len) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {

        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
            num[i] = str[i] - '0';
        } else {
            printf("ERROR: You entered a non-number\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        i++;
    }

}

// Does the check_digit formula on an EAN
int check_digit(int EAN[], int len) {

    int sum_pos = 0;
    int sum_neg = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum_pos += EAN[i];
        } else {
            sum_neg += EAN[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return (9 - (((sum_pos * 3) + sum_neg) - 1) % 10);
}
```

Comment: `check_digit(EAN_int, MAX_SIZE);` will always trigger `printf("ERROR: You entered a non-number\n");` and exit as it tests the _null character_.

Comment: `check_digit()` is checking 13 values unlike OP's 12.  Better to make use `#define MAX_SIZE 12`, `char EAN_str[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    int EAN_int[MAX_SIZE];`

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

OP wants to read a 12 digit code, yet `scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"...` looks for 12 separate `int`.

[@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235182/program-stuck-at-scanf#comment93356984_53235182) well suggested using `"%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d"` to limit the length of each `int` to 1 digit.

---

Alternative:

As [EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number()) can vary in length  up to 18 digits, consider

```
#define EAN_N 18
char buf[2*EAN_N];  // extra for \n, \0 and other other characters.
if (fgets(buf, sizof buf, stdin)) {
  int n = 0;
  while (buf[n] >= '0' && buf[n] <= '9') n++;
  if (buf[n] == '\n' || buf[n] == '\0' && <= EAN_N) {
    switch (n) {
       case 12: 
         // OP's original code
         break;
       case TBD: 
         // handle of cases TBD
    }
  }
}
```